# Cannot add NOT NULL constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to add a NOT NULL constraint to my table but it gives me this error:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'level_id', table
>   'project1.oc.courses'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails. The
>   statement has been terminated.

I also tried to insert a NULL value into level_id and it's possible. Any idea why do I get this error then?

```
CREATE TABLE oc.courses (
    course_id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1,1),
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    level_id INT,
    language_id INT,
    series_id INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (series_id) REFERENCES oc.series(series_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (level_id) REFERENCES oc.level(level_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (language_id) REFERENCES oc.language(language_id)
);

ALTER TABLE oc.courses
ALTER COLUMN level_id INT NOT NULL;
```

Comment: you need to fix all the existing nulls (UPDATE) before making the column disallow NULL

Comment: of course....time to sleep for me...thank you